# I get ENGINE-03018 Exception while try to run camunda docker with external postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, docker-compose, camunda

I am trying to set up an external postgresql database for camunda to work.
But when I run docker camunda with this config I get

> Exception ENGINE-03018 Could not check if tables are already present
> using metadata.

I don't know what to do about it.
Please help me with detailed answer, because I'm new in docker/java/postgres stack.

Using materials:

1. https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform

Configuration

```
postgres: 12.2
camunda: 7.13-snapshot
tomcat: 9.0.33
```

Docker-compose config

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"

  camunda:
    image: camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"      
    environment:
      - DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
      - DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/process-engine
      - DB_USERNAME=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - DB_VALIDATE_ON_BORROW=true
      - DB_VALIDATION_QUERY="SELECT 1"
```

Exception

```
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:51.462 SEVERE [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logError ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: ENGINE-03018 Could not check if tables are already present using metadata.
camunda_1                        |      org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-03018 Could not check if tables are already present using metadata.
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.EnginePersistenceLogger.checkDatabaseTableException(EnginePersistenceLogger.java:241)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.isTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:523)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.isEngineTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:463)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.AbstractPersistenceSession.dbSchemaUpdate(AbstractPersistenceSession.java:218)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.java:56)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.java:34)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:28)
...
```

Full log

```
camunda_1                        | Configure database
camunda_1                        | NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
camunda_1                        | NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.544 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.33
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 11 2020 09:31:38 UTC
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.33.0
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.557 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.558 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.558 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.558 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.4+4-alpine-r1
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.558 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Alpine
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /camunda
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /camunda
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/camunda/conf/logging.properties
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx768m
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/camunda
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/camunda
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/camunda/temp
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:41.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/../lib:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:42.584 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:42.721 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1,973] milliseconds
camunda_1                        | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
camunda_1                        | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils (file:/camunda/lib/postgresql-9.4.1212.jar) to field java.util.TimeZone.defaultTimeZone
camunda_1                        | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils
camunda_1                        | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
camunda_1                        | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:43.241 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-08046 Found camunda bpm platform configuration in CATALINA_BASE/CATALINA_HOME conf directory [/camunda/conf/bpm-platform.xml] at 'file:/camunda/conf/bpm-platform.xml'
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:43.574 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-12003 Plugin 'ProcessApplicationEventListenerPlugin' activated on process engine 'default'
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:43.582 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-12003 Plugin 'SpinProcessEnginePlugin' activated on process engine 'default'
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:43.587 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01010 Discovered Spin data format provider: org.camunda.spin.impl.json.jackson.format.JacksonJsonDataFormatProvider[name = application/json]
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:43.983 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01010 Discovered Spin data format provider: org.camunda.spin.impl.xml.dom.format.DomXmlDataFormatProvider[name = application/xml]
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:44.020 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01009 Discovered Spin data format: org.camunda.spin.impl.xml.dom.format.DomXmlDataFormat[name = application/xml]
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:44.020 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo SPIN-01009 Discovered Spin data format: org.camunda.spin.impl.json.jackson.format.JacksonJsonDataFormat[name = application/json]
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:44.020 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo ENGINE-12003 Plugin 'ConnectProcessEnginePlugin' activated on process engine 'default'
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:44.557 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo CNCT-01004 Discovered provider for connector id 'http-connector' and class 'org.camunda.connect.httpclient.impl.HttpConnectorImpl': 'org.camunda.connect.httpclient.impl.HttpConnectorProviderImpl'
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:44.560 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo CNCT-01004 Discovered provider for connector id 'soap-http-connector' and class 'org.camunda.connect.httpclient.soap.impl.SoapHttpConnectorImpl': 'org.camunda.connect.httpclient.soap.impl.SoapHttpConnectorProviderImpl'
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:44.904 INFO [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logInfo FEEL/SCALA-01001 Spin value mapper detected
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:45.312 INFO [main] org.camunda.feel.FeelEngine.<init> Engine created. [value-mapper: CompositeValueMapper(List(org.camunda.feel.impl.JavaValueMapper@8deb645, org.camunda.spin.plugin.impl.feel.integration.SpinValueMapper@7dd611c8)), function-provider: org.camunda.bpm.dmn.feel.impl.scala.function.CustomFunctionTransformer@496a31da, configuration: Configuration(false)]
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:51.462 SEVERE [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logError ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: ENGINE-03018 Could not check if tables are already present using metadata.
camunda_1                        |      org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-03018 Could not check if tables are already present using metadata.
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.EnginePersistenceLogger.checkDatabaseTableException(EnginePersistenceLogger.java:241)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.isTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:523)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.isEngineTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:463)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.AbstractPersistenceSession.dbSchemaUpdate(AbstractPersistenceSession.java:218)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.java:56)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.java:34)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:28)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:110)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:70)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl.executeSchemaOperations(ProcessEngineImpl.java:145)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl.<init>(ProcessEngineImpl.java:108)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:871)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.services.JmxManagedProcessEngineController.start(JmxManagedProcessEngineController.java:38)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.MBeanServiceContainer.startService(MBeanServiceContainer.java:77)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.MBeanServiceContainer.startService(MBeanServiceContainer.java:63)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.deployment.StartProcessEngineStep.performOperationStep(StartProcessEngineStep.java:116)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:120)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.MBeanServiceContainer.executeDeploymentOperation(MBeanServiceContainer.java:160)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation$DeploymentOperationBuilder.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:216)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.tomcat.TomcatBpmPlatformBootstrap.deployBpmPlatform(TomcatBpmPlatformBootstrap.java:83)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.tomcat.TomcatBpmPlatformBootstrap.lifecycleEvent(TomcatBpmPlatformBootstrap.java:61)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:923)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
camunda_1                        |      Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
camunda_1                        | ### Error getting a new connection.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
camunda_1                        | ### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.getConnection(DefaultSqlSession.java:299)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.isTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:498)
camunda_1                        |              ... 32 more
camunda_1                        |      Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:848)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:660)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.openConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:138)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:60)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.getConnection(DefaultSqlSession.java:297)
camunda_1                        |              ... 33 more
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:51.474 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
camunda_1                        |      org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
camunda_1                        |      Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-08043 Exception while performing 'deploy BPM platform' => 'Start process engine default': ENGINE-03018 Could not check if tables are already present using metadata.
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.ContainerIntegrationLogger.exceptionWhilePerformingOperationStep(ContainerIntegrationLogger.java:316)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:136)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.MBeanServiceContainer.executeDeploymentOperation(MBeanServiceContainer.java:160)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation$DeploymentOperationBuilder.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:216)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.tomcat.TomcatBpmPlatformBootstrap.deployBpmPlatform(TomcatBpmPlatformBootstrap.java:83)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.tomcat.TomcatBpmPlatformBootstrap.lifecycleEvent(TomcatBpmPlatformBootstrap.java:61)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:923)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
camunda_1                        |              ... 7 more
camunda_1                        |      Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-03018 Could not check if tables are already present using metadata.
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.EnginePersistenceLogger.checkDatabaseTableException(EnginePersistenceLogger.java:241)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.isTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:523)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.isEngineTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:463)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.AbstractPersistenceSession.dbSchemaUpdate(AbstractPersistenceSession.java:218)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.execute(SchemaOperationsProcessEngineBuild.java:56)
...
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.services.JmxManagedProcessEngineController.start(JmxManagedProcessEngineController.java:38)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.MBeanServiceContainer.startService(MBeanServiceContainer.java:77)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.MBeanServiceContainer.startService(MBeanServiceContainer.java:63)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.deployment.StartProcessEngineStep.performOperationStep(StartProcessEngineStep.java:116)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:120)
camunda_1                        |              ... 16 more
camunda_1                        |      Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
camunda_1                        | ### Error getting a new connection.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
camunda_1                        | ### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.getConnection(DefaultSqlSession.java:299)
camunda_1                        |              at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.sql.DbSqlSession.isTablePresent(DbSqlSession.java:498)
camunda_1                        |              ... 32 more
camunda_1                        |      Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:848)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:660)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.openConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:138)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:60)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.getConnection(DefaultSqlSession.java:297)
camunda_1                        |              ... 33 more
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:51.481 SEVERE [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logError ENGINE-08044 Exception while performing 'Stop managed thread pool': Cannot stop service org.camunda.bpm.platform:type=executor-service: no such service registered: service is null
camunda_1                        |      org.camunda.bpm.engine.exception.NullValueException: Cannot stop service org.camunda.bpm.platform:type=executor-service: no such service registered: service is null
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
...
camunda_1                        |              at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
camunda_1                        |              at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:51.482 SEVERE [main] org.camunda.commons.logging.BaseLogger.logError ENGINE-08044 Exception while performing 'Unregistering BPM Platform Plugins': Cannot stop service org.camunda.bpm.platform:type=bpm-platform-plugins: no such service registered: service is null
...
camunda_1                        | 07-Aug-2020 11:42:51.484 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Comment: try to add a `WAIT_FOR: postgres:5432` to the `camunda environment:` variables

Comment: Yes, i tried. Result was same.

Comment: Most likely not related to your problem, but is there  a reason why you specifically work with the 7.13-SNAPSHOT of camunda?